# Right click menu on popup/not popup form - MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, right-click

I encountered following problem:
I'm trying to use shortcut menu bar (shown after right click) as a tool for filtering existing query. Query has criteria based on textbox in the form and shortcut menu bar should allow entering a word, pass it to textbox and achieve filtering. Everything is working well as soon as form has popup property set to "yes". 
Poblem starts with regular form (popup property set to "no"). 
In such case shortcut menu bar is showing only control buttons (msoControlButton) but none edit box (msoControlEdit) or combo box (msoControlComboBox).

Does anybody know how to fix this problem? Every other form in my database is non-popup and it looks clunky with one form in other visual property.

EDIT:
Here is the code for commandbar:

```
Dim cmb As CommandBar
Dim CBB_nr1 As CommandBarButton

menu_name = "Menu"
CommandBars(menu_name).Delete

Set cmb = CommandBars.Add(menu_name, msoBarPopup, False, False)

With cmb
Set CBB_nr1 = .Controls.Add(msoControlEdit, , , , True)
    With CBB_nr1
        .BeginGroup = True
        .Caption = "Search:"
        .OnAction = "=Search()"
    End With
End With`
```

Here is the code for passing value to textbox (placed in Function Search()):

```
Forms("Form_name").Textbox_name = Nz(CommandBars("Menu").Controls("Search:").Text, "*")
```

The main problem is that Textbox and Combobox line does not show in created commandbar if form is not in popup mode.

Comment: How does shortcut menu filter input pass a value to a textbox? I have never seen this. Post your code for analysis.

Comment: @June7 - I edited main post to make the code more clear.